# How to skip lines when writing to a file from web page?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a script that grabs web page data from many different pages and writes the data to a txt file. However, from each web page, the first 1200 lines of HTML I do not need, so I'd like to skip those line and write the rest to my txt file.

Is there a way to do this or should I skip reading them first when I retrieve the URL? Thanks

```
import requests
from requests import session

payload = {
    'action': 'login',
    'username': '',
    'password': ''
}


with session() as c: #Create a cookie session to login to the protected page
    page_offset = 0 
    result_list = []
    c.post('login page url here', payload)
    while page_offset <= 1000:
        url = "actual url to scrape"
        request = c.get(url)

        if not request.ok:
                print ("error")
                # Something went wrong

        for block in request.iter_content(1024):
                if not block:
                        break

                result_list.append(block)
        page_offset += 25
        #print (page_offset)
        #print (result_list)
        end_data = ','.join([str(i) for i in result_list])

with open("terapeak.txt", 'wb') as text_file:
    text_file.write(bytes(end_data.strip(),'UTF-8'))
```

Comment: What is the html like? Is it separated by newlines?

Comment: The text file was too big for pastebin so here is the dropbox link https://www.dropbox.com/s/9mmbbk53y8wilm2/example.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to partially download an HTML page. You will have just skip these lines you don't need. Especially if you know the exact number. So while you read your html page line by line, count the lines and write only ones which number is higher than the required. 1200 in your case.